# Make a HTML vertical img slider like Dopper.com project

Tags: html, css, wagtail

I am trying to make a slider for my wagtail website.
The look i am aiming for is something like the project slider on [dopper.com](https://dopper.com)
I tried to copy it for now and changing it after it works somewhat.
What i have now:

html

```html
<div id="green">
    <div id="_3Y_4omKhBxgsJWab0Pvtfb">
        <div id="ZqeD7GpvyYA2hpsM2zSgE">
                {% for img in self.imgs %}
                    <div style="z-index: 4; transform: translate3d(0%, 0px, 0px); width: 100%; display: flex">
                        {% image img.img width-500 as tmp_photo %}
                        <img src="{{ tmp_photo.url }}" id="box" style="height: 20vh; align-self: flex-end; position: relative; transform: scale(1.2); width: 80%; min-width: 160px; max-width: 400px; overflow: hidden">
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
    #green{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
        font-size: 100%;
        vertical-align: baseline;
    }

    #_3Y_4omKhBxgsJWab0Pvtfb{
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    #ZqeD7GpvyYA2hpsM2zSgE{
        width: 430%;
    }
```

I just cannot get the images side by side and after that the animation. Is there not something on the internet already that does something like this it tried googling a lot but did not find anything.